# How to select classes with this id to trigger an event / how to change the color of the header per each slides?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is what I'm trying to do: if this document has this class and this class has this id, then change the header background color. I have been trying to do if statements and using .is() to also select the id element, but it is not working.

I'm trying to create a slide webpage with a fixed header. I'm trying to change the color of the header per each slide.

Here is some HTML

```
<header id="header">
  <h2 id="dialogues-header">HEADER—</h2>
  <h2 id="spring-right">Spring 2020</h2>
</header>

<div class="mySlides" id="grey-header">
  <div class="container">

    <main class="main-one">
        <img class="artwork" src="image.jpg" />
    </main>

    <aside class="info">
            <h3>Header</h3>

        <div class="text-blurb">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <main class="main-two yellow">
        <h1 id="number">1</h1>
        <h1 id="name-right">name</h1>
    </main>

    <main class="main-three">
            <iframe src="link"></iframe>
    </main> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides" id="yellow-header"> same as above </div>
```

Here is some css

```
header {
position: fixed;
/*-- other code omitted --*/
}
```

Here is the jquery code

```
<script>
var yellowHeader = $(".mySlides").is("#yellow-header");
var greyHeader = $(".mySlides").is("#grey-header");
var pinkHeader = $(".mySlides").is("#pink-header");


if (yellowHeader) {
$('header').css({"background-color":"#FFF231"});
} if (greyHeader) {
$('header').css({"background-color":"#F4F4F4"});
}
</script>
```

**EDITS:**
Hey, I think people aren't getting what I'm trying to do? So I added more of my code here for you to check out --> https://codepen.io/youngua/pen/bGEpwyd

On Header 1 slide: Header 0 should be grey, Header 2 slide: Header 0 should be yellow, Header 3 slide: Header 0 should be pink

That's what I'm trying to do

Comment: why don't you use CSS?

Comment: @djcaesar9114 how would I go about using CSS? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well if what you want is `pink-header` having `"background-color":"#FFF231"`, just put it in the CSS...

Comment: @djcaesar9114 I understand that I can do that, but what I'm asking for is to change the background color of a fixed header for each slide on the webpage. I updated my question to include a codepen repository if you would like to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first of all put all your JS in separate files, not in the HTML file.
Then, use CSS and DOM logic. What you want is everytime you change a slide, the color of the header changes, it means that everytime you change a slide, your header gets a new class:

https://codepen.io/djcaesar9114/pen/mdVPmaV

In your CSS

```
.pink-header {
  background-color: pink;
}
.yellow-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.grey-header {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

And in your JS

```
 document.getElementById('header').className = (x[slideIndex - 1].getAttribute('id'));
```

What this line is doing:

- getting the slide you want to be displayed: `x[slideIndex - 1]`
- taking its id: `.getAttribute('id')`
- taking this id and putting it as a class for the header: `document.getElementById('header').className =`

It means that if your slide has the id "pink-header", so "#pink-header" in CSS, your header gets the class "pink-header", so ".pink-header" in CSS.

Comment: This works!!! Thank you so much! I was wondering, how do getAttribute() recognize which specific id to select? And how does it recognize in the css file that it should use .pink-header (it's a .class not #id ) and the others to change the background-color? I guess I'll need to got back and study DOM logic

Comment: WOW! I didn't know that was possible for id to be translated to class?! Yes, the explanation is clear. I have much to learn!

Comment: You can do whatever you want when you code. Keep it up, we always have something to learn!

Answer (score 0):

i run your code,it's work

[codepen](https://codepen.io/wzc570738205/pen/oNbbrBx)

i think you can try to change color

```
if (yellowHeader) {
$('header').css({"background-color":"red"});
} 
if (greyHeader) {
$('header').css({"background-color":"blue"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making multiple conditional statements, you must chain the if statement with if-else. I corrected the jQuery below. Remember that it will go through each statement in order, and if the first statement is true it will not continue through the chain

```js
var yellowHeader = $(".mySlides").is("#yellow-header");
var greyHeader = $(".mySlides").is("#grey-header");
var pinkHeader = $(".mySlides").is("#pink-header");


if (yellowHeader) {
$('header').css({"background-color":"#FFF231"});
} else if (greyHeader) {
$('header').css({"background-color":"#F4F4F4"});
}
```

```css
header {
position: fixed;
/*-- other code omitted --*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <h2 id="dialogues-header">HEADER—</h2>
  <h2 id="spring-right">Spring 2020</h2>
</header>

<div class="mySlides" id="grey-header">
  <div class="container">

    <main class="main-one">
        <img class="artwork" src="image.jpg" />
    </main>

    <aside class="info">
            <h3>Header</h3>

        <div class="text-blurb">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <main class="main-two yellow">
        <h1 id="number">1</h1>
        <h1 id="name-right">name</h1>
    </main>

    <main class="main-three">
            <iframe src="link"></iframe>
    </main> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides" id="yellow-header"> same as above </div>
```